# Finding equilibrium points of nonlinear differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-system

I have to find the equilibrium points of a nonlinear system:

```
x1' =  .51*sqrt(x1) + .076*u
x2' = -.51*sqrt(x1) + .51*sqrt(x2) + .136*u
```

I have assumed that u is arbitrary, so I substituted it for 1. So far I have equated

`x1' = .51*sqrt(x1bar) + .076 = 0`
`x2' =  -.51*sqrt(x1bar) + .51*sqrt(x2bar) + .136 = 0`

which resulted in

```
sqrt(x1bar) = -.076/.51
x1bar = .0222

-.51(sqrt(x1bar) - sqrt(x2bar)) = -.136
sqrt(.0222) - sqrt(x2bar) = .136/.51
x2bar = .01384

xbar = (.0222, .01384)
```

Then I took the Jacobian of the system for the points above

```
J(x,y) = [1.71       0   ]
         [ -1.71   2.1675]
```

Am I on the right track or have I done this completely wrong?

Comment: "I have assumed that u is arbitrary, so I substituted it for 1." Huh? Since u is arbitrary you are supposed to solve this for every u, not for some specific u. Furthermore, if u=1 there is no equilibrium, so how did you find this xbar?

Comment: So are you saying that the system's equilibrium points depends on the input?

Comment: This seems obvious, no? (Assuming that, by "the input" you mean the parameter u.)

Comment: I thought that for the equilibrium point(s) of this system are independent of the input